# Why do I get less running threads than the work I send to thread pool

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm running a simple console migration.
I bundled the workload by batches of 750 items and send it to my ThreadPool via:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(workerArray[i]._DoWork, i);
```

I added some logs in the execution of the _DoWork method, and it outputs:

```
Thread 1 started working...
Thread 2 started working...
Thread 1 is done working
```

for more than 400 times

But at each start and end I also log the number of threads running via outputing 
 (which I found in SO):

```
((IEnumerable)System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads)
                .OfType<System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread>()
                .Where(t => t.ThreadState == System.Diagnostics.ThreadState.Running)
                .Count();
```

But why does it only output 2 to 4 threads when I have over 100 started threads and none done yet?

=============

Some more code

Here's what's queueing the work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < taskCount; i++)
        {
            int itemCount = queueLength;

            if (i * queueLength + itemCount > journalIDs.Count)
                itemCount = (journalIDs.Count) - (i * queueLength);

            var queue = journalIDs.GetRange(i * queueLength, itemCount);

            doneEvents[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            dbWorkers[i] = new DBWorker();

            var loadedQueue = db.GetJournalByIDs(queue);

            workerArray[i] = new JournalWorker(dbWorkers[i], loadedQueue, doneEvents[i]);

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(workerArray[i]._DoWork, i);
        }
```

Here's what the DoWork does:

public void _DoWork(Object pThreadContext) {

```
        int theThreadIndex = (int)pThreadContext;
        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} started...", theThreadIndex);
        var threads = ((IEnumerable)System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads)
                .OfType<System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread>()
                .Where(t => t.ThreadState == System.Diagnostics.ThreadState.Running)
                .Count();

        Console.WriteLine("There's {0} thread(s) currently running", threads);

        foreach (var item in Queue)
        {

            var update = ShouldUpdate(item);

            if (update != null)
            {
                //Do some db operation
            }
            else
            {
                //Do some db operation
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} started saving...", theThreadIndex);
        Save(Store);

        Console.WriteLine("Thread {0} done working with " + Store.Count + " objects...", theThreadIndex);

        threads = ((IEnumerable)System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads)
                .OfType<System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread>()
                .Where(t => t.ThreadState == System.Diagnostics.ThreadState.Running)
                .Count();
        Console.WriteLine("There's {0} thread(s) currently running", threads);
        db.Clear();
        db = null;
        _doneEvent.Set();


    }
```

Comment: Start by distinguishing between Threads and WorkItems

Comment: The point of a thread pool is to have less actual threads than assigned tasks....

Comment: I get the part where I'm queuing my 400 tasks, and waiting for the queue to be emptied one by one by free thread.
But I'm getting some opening connection error toward the database because I have more than 250 connections open, which I shouldn't have as my accesses are enclosed by using blocks.
How can I tell him to not take another task if the thread is not 100% free ?

Comment: Totally unrelated and hard to understand. Seems you have too many threads now.

Comment: Ask about your actual problem, and document it with a [mcve].

Comment: Here you go, I cannot reduce the code as it would hurt the comprehension, (_DoWork is a method from an abstract class every children classes will call to do their work)

Comment: This is neither minimal nor complete, we can't see anything related to your DbConnections. And it looks like you should just use `Paralle.ForEach()`

Comment: Your problem looks like you're sharing the connections among threads

Comment: @HenkHolterman
The question is why I have 100 threads actually doing things, and the line GetCurrentProcess().Threads gives me only 4.
I don't get why does Db would have an impact (And I cannot publish the whole code)

Comment: "cannot publish the whole code" - that's Ok, we don't want to read it all. Click on this [mcve] link, it  really talks about you and your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of things to consider here

- ThreadPool maximum concurrent threads defaults based on several different factors in .NET 4.0. You can check the actual value by calling GetMaxThreads
- When waiting for a ManualResetEvent, the ThreadState will be WaitSleepJoin, not Running
- Console is thread safe but won't give you predictable, accurately timed, correctly ordered output when used in a multithreaded scenario